# Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title' -> due to an empty class

Tags: python, xpath

I am looping through an xpath getting all the bold text that has the class black.

this then gets the title within the bold class. This works fine until I have come across one the is blank inside.

Using the below code how can i edit it to remove/skip the class's that contain no data?

```
out = [b.text.title() + "##" +  b.xpath("./following::text()[1]")[0].lstrip(",") for b in div.xpath(".//b[@class='black']")]
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

due to this line:

`<b class="black"></b>`

if it helps the div.xpath is:

```
div = tree.xpath("//*[@id='ANALYSIS']")[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a filter to your list comprehension:

```
out = [b.text.title() + "##" +  b.xpath("./following::text()[1]")[0].lstrip(",")
       for b in div.xpath(".//b[@class='black']")
       if b.text]
```

The `if b.text` ensures there is a truthy (non-empty or not `None`) `b.text` attribute value.

Comment: brill thanks - didnt think of that (have tried altering the text itself and all sorts)